# No shape error in tensorflow graph construction but getting shape mismatch error during graph computation

Tags: tensorflow, invalid-argument

There occurs no error in tensorflow graph construction, but I get a shape mismatch error during graph computation in `tf.gradients` (I guess that the error is in back propagation).

This is the error I get:

> InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback):
>   Input to reshape is a tensor with 16777216 values, but the requested shape has 4096
>   [[Node: gradients/truediv_grad/Reshape = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0
>       /device:GPU:0"](gradients/truediv_grad/Sum, gradients/truediv_grad/Shape)]]

Comment: Could you put together a snippet which reproduces the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue , using two techniques:

1.Apparently if you are creating custom ops and gradients , you need to be very explicit in providing the shape information to tensorflow using `set_shape` or `tf.reshape`

2.Also when you are registering your gradient using `tf.register_gradient` which takes op and grad as inputs, you need to be careful while chaining the gradients i.e `dy/dx = dy/dz*dz/dx`.
Say `dy/dz` is the custom gradient we have created and `dz/dx`is the gradient of the previous ops as per the chain rule of differentiation.

```
tf.register_gradient(Mygrad)
def Mygrad(op,grad):
*****do stuff with op.inputs and calculate custom grads say cust_grad or dy/dz****
return cust_grad*grad
```

I changed this to following:

```
tf.register_gradient(Mygrad)
def Mygrad(op,grad):
*****do stuff with op.inputs and calculate custom grads say cust_grad or dy/dz****
return tf.matmul(tf.reshape(cust_grad,[calculated_shape]),tf.reshape(grad,expeced_shape))
```